# Trim filepath inside XML file element

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get the last piece of the file name inside a XML document. Currently, some users are sending over complete filepaths but not all of them. I know how to do the trim when dealing with a physical file but not when the path is contained inside the "nc:DocumentFileControlID" element of the XML which is under the "ecf:DocumentRendition" element. I am wanting the path after the last "\" and before the .pdf or .doc file extension.

C# code:

```
private void btnGet_File_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File";
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"filepath";
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = TextBox1.Text;
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = TextBox1.Text + "|*.xml";

    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string b64str = null;
    byte[] binaryData = null;
    System.IO.FileStream fs = null;
    XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(fileToOpen);

    ListBox1.Items.Clear();

    while (xr.Read())
    {
        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.Name == "nc:DocumentFileControlID")
        {
            fileToSave = xr.ReadElementString();
            if (fileToSave.Contains(".pdf") || fileToSave.Contains(".doc"))
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(fileToSave);
            }
        }
        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.Name == "nc:BinaryBase64Object")
        {
            b64str = xr.ReadElementString();
            binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(b64str);

            fileToSave = "C:\\xml_images\\" + fileToSave;
            fs = new FileStream(fileToSave, FileMode.Create);

            // write it out
            fs.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);

            // close it down.
            fs.Close();
            binaryData = null;
            fileToSave = null;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("All files are saved in C:\\xml_images");
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RecordFilingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServiceMessagingProfile-Definitions-4.0">
  <RecordFilingRequestMessage xmlns:fsrsp="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:FilingStatusResponseMessage-4.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0" xmlns:j="http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:juvenile="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:JuvenileCase-4.0" xmlns:niem-xsd="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0" xmlns:domestic="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:DomesticCase-4.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:criminal="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CriminalCase-4.0" xmlns:amcadext="http://www.amcad.com/NiemEcf/extensions/1.0" xmlns:i="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0" xmlns:appellate="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:AppellateCase-4.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:citation="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CitationCase-4.0" xmlns:reviewcb="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:ReviewFilingCallbackMessage-4.0" xmlns:civil="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CivilCase-4.0">

  <FilingLeadDocument s:id="DOC00001" s:metadata="# Pages=4">
    <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="Service Documents">Alias Summons Returned Served</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">101</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2013-10-02T09:57:49.4565724-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2013-10-02T09:57:48.463-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
    <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
    <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
      <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2090267461">7645</j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
      <ecf:FilingPartyID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>17291</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </ecf:FilingPartyID>
      <ecf:SpecialHandlingInstructions />
    </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
    <ecf:DocumentRendition>
      <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID>H:\`BCA E-Filing Folder\EFRAIN\13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00001">
```

Comment: get the node value then use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) against it

Comment: @Jonesy can you explain for me? that would be coded along the first "IF" statement right since it refers to the file info?

Comment: var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileToSave);

Comment: @Ian Gilroy that is returning the complete file name but now the file is not showing up in my C:\\xml_images\\ folder. Where do I need to place it within the code to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

You need to extract the data from the element node's value first. I have taken your xml and parsed it using Linq to Xml and extracted the value. Note that there are many DocumentFileControlIDs and I just looked for one which has a c: or h: type pattern to discriminate. Your processing will be different.

```
    XNamespace nc = "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0";
    
    var node =
    XElement.Parse(GetXMlData())
            .Descendants(nc + "DocumentFileControlID")
            .Where (element => Regex.IsMatch(element.Value, @"(^[A-Z]\:)"))
        //  .Select (element => Path.GetFileName(element.Value)) // Use this to just get the filename.
            .FirstOrDefault();
    
    Console.WriteLine (node); // <nc:DocumentFileControlID xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">H:\`BCA E-Filing Folder\EFRAIN\13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    
    Console.WriteLine (Path.GetFileName(node.Value));   
//  13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf
```

GetData looks like this:

```
public string GetXMlData()
{
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<RecordFilingRequest xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XML" +
    "Schema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"urn:oasis:n" +
    "ames:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServiceMessagingProfile-Definitions-4.0\">\r\n" +
    "  <RecordFilingRequestMessage xmlns:fsrsp=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfili" +
    "ng:schema:xsd:FilingStatusResponseMessage-4.0\" xmlns:ecf=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:leg" +
    "alxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0\" xmlns:j=\"http://niem.gov/niem/doma" +
    "ins/jxdm/4.0\" xmlns:juvenile=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd" +
    ":JuvenileCase-4.0\" xmlns:niem-xsd=\"http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0\" xmlns:dom" +
    "estic=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:DomesticCase-4.0\" xmln" +
    "s:s=\"http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0\" xmlns:criminal=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:leg" +
    "alxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CriminalCase-4.0\" xmlns:amcadext=\"http://www.amcad." +
    "com/NiemEcf/extensions/1.0\" xmlns:i=\"http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0\" xmlns:app" +
    "ellate=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:AppellateCase-4.0\" xm" +
    "lns:nc=\"http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0\" xmlns:citation=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:l" +
    "egalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CitationCase-4.0\" xmlns:reviewcb=\"urn:oasis:names" +
    ":tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:ReviewFilingCallbackMessage-4.0\" xmlns:civil" +
    "=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CivilCase-4.0\">\r\n\r\n  <Filin" +
    "gLeadDocument s:id=\"DOC00001\" s:metadata=\"# Pages=4\">\r\n    <nc:DocumentApplicati" +
    "onName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>\r\n    <nc:DocumentDescription" +
    "Text s:id=\"Service Documents\">Alias Summons Returned Served</nc:DocumentDescript" +
    "ionText>\r\n    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id=\"FileInputId\">101</nc:DocumentFileC" +
    "ontrolID>\r\n    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id=\"Rule6PublicAnswer\">-1</nc:Documen" +
    "tFileControlID>\r\n    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id=\"Rule6ConfidentialAnswer\">-1" +
    "</nc:DocumentFileControlID>\r\n    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id=\"TypeOfConfident" +
    "ialDocument\">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>\r\n    <nc:DocumentPostDate>\r\n      <nc" +
    ":DateTime>2013-10-02T09:57:49.4565724-04:00</nc:DateTime>\r\n    </nc:DocumentPost" +
    "Date>\r\n    <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>\r\n      <nc:DateTime>2013-10-02T09:57:48.463" +
    "-04:00</nc:DateTime>\r\n    </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>\r\n    <nc:DocumentSequenceID" +
    ">1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>\r\n    <ecf:DocumentMetadata>\r\n      <j:RegisterActionD" +
    "escriptionText s:id=\"2090267461\">7645</j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>\r\n      <" +
    "ecf:FilingPartyID>\r\n        <nc:IdentificationID>17291</nc:IdentificationID>\r\n  " +
    "      <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>\r\n" +
    "      </ecf:FilingPartyID>\r\n      <ecf:SpecialHandlingInstructions />\r\n    </ecf" +
    ":DocumentMetadata>\r\n    <ecf:DocumentRendition>\r\n      <ecf:DocumentRenditionMet" +
    "adata>\r\n        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicat" +
    "ionName>\r\n        <nc:DocumentFileControlID>H:\\`BCA E-Filing Folder\\EFRAIN\\13-25" +
    "6382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>\r\n        <ecf:Document" +
    "Attachment s:id=\"ATT00001\"/>\r\n\t   </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>\r\n\t</ecf:Docum" +
    "entRendition>\r\n</FilingLeadDocument>\r\n</RecordFilingRequestMessage>\r\n</RecordFil" +
    "ingRequest>";

}
```

---

### Original

Use Path.GetFileName which will figure out whether the file has a path or not and just return the filename.

```
Path.GetFileName(@"H:\`BCA E-Filing Folder\EFRAIN\13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf")
    
    /* returns
     13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf
    */
```

Comment: this is still returning the complete path and not just the file name after the last "\".

Comment: @clerktech something else is happening then...is the process you have to get the node value getting something else along with it? Can you verify the *actual string* which is being passed into the method call?

Comment: I am actually getting the value of the node(element). I just want to strip out the entire path before the last "\".

Comment: @clerktech between the two people who have answered, we are missing something. Can you update your post to show the value of the node element you actually get (outside your code snippet) and then what you expect this process after getting the node value should return.

Comment: @clerktech The process I describe does not update any xml...do you want the xml updated? Maybe that is the misunderstanding.

Comment: I can get the value of that element. Once I have it, I need to strip out everything before the last "\". What is happening is that these end users are including the entire path of their files which is making my program bomb because it is an invalid file path to save to my C:/ drive.

Comment: in the XML above, the element value is "<nc:DocumentFileControlID>H:\`BCA E-Filing Folder\EFRAIN\13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>". Of course this will be different for each person filing as it is done from the outside vendor tool.

Comment: @clerktech can you provide the XML namespaces that go along with your xml?

Comment: the namespaces are now added.

Comment: @clerktech added XDocument processing to extract the filename and extension.

Comment: how would I implement this with my current code setup. If possible, can I use the Replace or Regex methods to remove the slashes to underscores?

Comment: Is this a side requirement to trim the path? It is unclear looking at the code you provided that it is doing something such as a post processing step with the path after getting it. But yes, once you have the path in a string, you can then use regex place on that string.

Comment: It works. Had to tinker with it a little bit. thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("H:\BCA E-Filing Folder\EFRAIN\13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1.pdf");
```

That will get

> 13-256382_FC01_SUMMONS_BREVARD1